# how can $\sqrt{2}/4=1/2^{3/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$\sqrt{2}/4=1/2^{3/2}$ this is a subpart of a work example question I have but I don't understand how I can convert the first part into the second.

Comment: use $$\frac{2^m}{2^n}=2^{m-n}$$

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore but wouldn't that equale to $2^{-1/2}$ not $1/2^{3/2}$?

Comment: maryjames Isnt $\frac{1}{2}-2=-\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore owww i see we have to change the 4 into $2^2$Thank you very much its these small mistakes where i get stuck on a question for a long time what is this rule called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt2}{2^2} = \frac{2^\frac{1}{2}}{2^2} =2^{-\frac{3}{2}} =
\frac{1}{2^\frac{3}{2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\require{cancel}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{\cancel{\sqrt{2}}}{\cancel{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^3}=\frac{1}{(2^{1/2})^3}=\frac{1}{2^{3/2}}.$$

Or,

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{2^{1/2}}{2^2} = 2^{(1/2)-2} = 2^{-3/2}=\frac{1}{2^{3/2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rationalize the numerator $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}×\sqrt{2}}{4×\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=\frac{2}{4\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2×2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^3}}=\frac{1}{(2^3)^\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2^\frac{3}{2}}$$